# JavaScript function with array length parametrs

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization

Ok, i'm realised random array of 100,500,1000,etc. elements from 0 to 3m.

```
var array1 = [];
for (var k= 0, t=100; k<t; k++){
    array1.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 3000000))
};
var array2 = [];
for (var k= 0, t=500; k<t; k++){
    array2.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 3000000))
};
```

I repeated this 8 times for different lengths of array. So i want to optimise this with function that do this algorithm and behind the function i'm only declaring the length of array that i need. So it can be like this

```
var [100,500,1000,10000] //number of lengths
function().... // doing algorithm
console.log(array1) // array of 100 elements
console.log(array2) // array of 500 elements
etc...
```

So how to realise this?

Comment: Looks pretty trivial, have you tried writing such a function yet? Declare an array, iterate through the `for` loop to populate it, and then return the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write a function that takes the length of the desired array as a parameter. It's pretty simple, just always look what the differences in your code are, then replace them with a variable. Taken from your code, this would be

```js
function createArrayWithLength(length) {
  var array1 = [];
  for (var k = 0, t = length; k < t; k++) {
    array1.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 3000000))
  };
  return array1;
}

console.log(createArrayWithLength(3));
```

You could also have it a bit easier, taking below function instead to create your array:

```js
function createArrWithLength(length) {
  return Array.from({length}, () => Math.round(Math.random() * 3000000));
}
console.log(createArrWithLength(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```js
var sizes = [100,500,1000,10000] //number of lengths
var result_arr = [];

for(var i=0;i<sizes.length;i++){
  result_arr[i] = getRandomArray(sizes[i]);
}

  console.log(result_arr);


function getRandomArray(size){
  var array = [];
  for (var k= 0; k<size; k++){
      array.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 3000000))
  };
  return array;
}
```